# javascript clone a tree of elements and change all the IDs in the clone

Tags: javascript, clone

i created a button that allows you to clone a tree of elements. This is my code:

```
   function add_party(number) {
    var n = number.replace("party", ""); 
    var newparty = document.getElementById("party"+n);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var con = document.getElementById("party1").innerHTML;
    document.createElement("div");
    div.id = 'party' + ++n;
    div.innerHTML = con;
    newparty.parentNode.insertBefore(div, newparty.nextSibling);
    renumberDivs(div, n, "div","party");
   }
```

This is my HTML:

```
   <div id="party1">
    <h1>Party 1</h1>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th>party name：</th>
       <td><input type="text" name="name1" value="some name"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>party time：</th>
      <td><input type="text" name="time1" value="some time"></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="button" onclick="add_party(this.parentNode.id)" value="add party">
  </div>
```

However, since each element has an unique ID or name the clone should not have the same IDs or names. Instead the new IDs and names should add up by 1. So the cloned tree should look like this:

```
   <div id="party2">
    <h1>Party 2</h1>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th>party name：</th>
       <td><input type="text" name="name2" value=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>party time：</th>
      <td><input type="text" name="time2" value=""></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="button" onclick="add_party(this.parentNode.id)" value="add party">
  </div>
```

Also, the input values should be empty for the clone. How can i do it with javascript? (no jQuery please).

Thank you.

EDIT:

this code updates the count numbers so they always appear in order:

```
function renumberDivs(el, n, tagn, ass) {
    while (el = el.nextSibling) {
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagn){
      el.id = ass + ++n;
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this solution is a 2-step process:

1. manipulate existing parties one by one from the last to the insert point.
2. insert new party to the insert point.

```js
function add_party(divId) {
    var party = document.getElementById(divId);
    var newParty = party.cloneNode(true);
    var allParties = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="party"]');
    var newId = parseInt(divId.replace('party', ''), 10) + 1;

    for(var i = allParties.length-1; i > newId-2; i--) {
        allParties[i].setAttribute('id', 'party' + (i+2));
        allParties[i].querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'Party ' + (i+2);
        var partyInputs = allParties[i].querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
        for(var j = 0; j < partyInputs.length; j++) {
            var prefix = partyInputs[j].getAttribute("name").replace(/\d+/, "");
            partyInputs[j].setAttribute("name", prefix + (i+2));
        }
    }

    newParty.setAttribute('id', 'party' + newId);
    newParty.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'Party ' + newId;
    var inputs = newParty.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var prefix = inputs[i].getAttribute("name").replace(/\d+/, "");
        inputs[i].setAttribute("name", prefix + newId);
        inputs[i].setAttribute("value", "");
        inputs[i].value = "";
    }

    party.parentNode.insertBefore(newParty, party.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<div id="party1">
    <h1>Party 1</h1>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>party name：</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="name1" value="some name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>party time：</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="time1" value="some time"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="add_party(this.parentNode.id)" value="add party">
</div>
```

Comment: We are almost there, but there are still 2 issues: first off, the new party should appear right below the one with the button that was pressed (my original code does that) and secondly, since we got new parties in between the old ones, then the numbers in the count wont match. I added the code to my question that updates the old numbers to the new ones. However i cant find a way to combine your code with mine.

Comment: @CainNuke Say, you click add button, now you have 1 and 2. Then you click add button of 1, you want to insert a party between 1 and 2, AND you want the newly added to be 2, and original 2 becomes 3. Is that your desired?

Comment: @CainNuke answer updated, see if it's what you want?

Comment: Yes, now its perfect. Thank you so much. Now just one question: what does this line exactly do? parseInt(divId.replace('party', ''), 10) + 1;

Comment: `divId` is the id of DIV which contains the button you clicked, for example `"party2"`. `divId.replace('party', '')` retrieves the number part, `"2"`. But this is still a string (which presents a number), so we use `parseInt`, convert to a decimal number. Then `+1` to get the ID number for newly added party.

Comment: The "10" there means it will convert to a decimal number?

Comment: Yes, it means try to parse the string as a decimal. Another example, `parseInt('11', 2)` will try to parse 11 as a binary number, and you get a decimal 3. If you want to convert 3 to a binary number, you can use `(3).toString(2)`, it returns `11`.

Comment: I see. In this case, what would happen without that line?

Comment: For example you clicked button within ID 2, new party is inserted under it and you want to give ID 3 to the new party. Original party 3 should now become party 4, right?

Comment: So, what this line do is, get number 2 from the string id "party2", and plus 1, then we get 3, this is for the new party.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. Now i understand your code much better.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better attach event to element using `addEventListener`. I found it works fun. Please refer to [**DEMO...**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLwjcz1n/1/), but there is a question, for the new generated form, there is no event handler attached, so you should attach new event handler for new generated form. if you can use jQuery or some others, you can use function like [Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) that bind event handler automatically